# How to create advanced input with filter in results

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to make something really similar as "search" on website http://www.jobs.cz/

**What it should do:**

- Selectbox show on user focus on input
- User can type in input and filter result from selectbox
- If user pick one of result selectbox hide
- If user focus input again selectbox open again and user can pick another option (pick as added to previous not rewrite previous one)
- If he start typing to input it still filter no matter what is already picked
  (example: He already pick "Administrativa" but if he type Auto it offer him "Auto - Moto", in another words, values picked before should not be use for filter )
- Each picked value should be in some "tag" mode (each one is separated inline-block and have class)

Before I will continue i dont want you to make whole code for me it will prolly take too long, And I didnt come here for code but mostly for HOW TO design something like this. I start my self with multiple things just dont know if I think right and I need to help with some ideas how things like this can be made.

**So what I did:**

- *Opening / Closing selectbox div:*

Input looks like:

```
<input id="position" placeholder="Position" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" ng-model="q">
```

And then something like

```
<div class="inputHelper" ng-show="focus">
```

- *Filter results:*

Based on angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) filter in ng-repeat should be done really easy by:

```
<li ng-repeat="pos in listCtrl.positions | filter:q as results" ng-click="listCtrl.choosePosition(pos)">{{pos.name}}</li>
```

With `ng-model="q"` on `<input>` , however problem start if I push something to that model, like previous pick from user. I am not sure how to handle filter if user already pick something.

- *Handle multiple picks*

For this I create array where I always check if user already pick that, if not push it to array.

```
choosePosition: function(position) {
    if (listCtrl.chosenPosition.indexOf(position) === -1) {
        listCtrl.chosenPosition.push(position);
    }
}
```

- *Show array of objects in input*

I search for this a lot in documentation and google a this kind of issue, and I found [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) what is basicly display array in input. I didnt  find anything more usefull. So for this point I dont know how to display array of objects, and how to style each array element as inline block and give it some class.

**Summary:**

This is kind of long post, but I try to say everything I need to do to avoid some miss understanding, I spend  days here I still stuck somewhere. And I am not even sure I design this well. If here is someone who can help me with part of codes which can work or at least try to explain me how to do something like this i will really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If your project will allow its use, [Angular Material's Autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) is pretty much a direct implementation of what you desire.

Comment: Hi @pulse0ne thank you for answer, I feel like Angular Material's Autocomplete doesnt support multiple pick. Atleast I cant find it there.

Comment: @Andurit ah, I had not selected anything on the jobs site the first time around...that does complicate things. There may be a way to 'massage' it enough to work. But in my experience, Material's component design is very opinionated and inflexible.

Comment: @Andurit perhaps you could wrap the whole thing in a div and have the tag 'chips' be siblings of your autocomplete input, with some dynamic layout. Inspecting the source of the linked page you provided, it seems they're doing something along those lines